# Find an XSL node by one child value, then change another child value in that node

Tags: xml, xslt

So I know how to find a node based upon one of it's child values, but how would I go about finding an xml node by one child value, then changing another child value of that node accordingly. i.e. if I wanted to find a dog node by it's name tag, then change it's breed tag.

```
<dog>
    <name>Fido</name>
    <breed>GSD</breed>
</dog>
```

should become:

```
<dog>
    <name>Fido</name>
    <breed>Labrador</breed>
</dog>
```

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Please show how you identify a node by one child value and change it, i.e. post your code. Show the result if gives you and fabricate (by manually editing) the result you want. That will make giving you a helpful answer much easier. The idea is called [mcve].

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem or are you still having issues?

Comment: @DanielHaley Your answer got me started on the right track. I will add what I ultimately did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you could just match the `breed` in the `dog` with the `name` "Fido" like this...

```
<xsl:template match="dog[name='Fido']/breed">
  <breed>Labrador</breed>
</xsl:template>
```

But you said in a comment:

> how would it handle doing that if say the name was a variable passed in through xsltproc?

In XSLT 1.0 you can't reference a variable or parameter in a `match` statement. You would need to use an `xsl:choose` to check the `name` (updated to also pass the breed in as an xsl:param, but it's not strictly necessary)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="animalName" select="'Fido'"/>
  <xsl:param name="animalBreed" select="'Labrador'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="breed">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="../name=$animalName">
        <breed><xsl:value-of select="$animalBreed"/></breed>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0 you could just change the match to `dog[name=$animalName]/breed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *identity template* and a replacement template replacing specific `<breed>` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replaces <breed> elements with specific text content --> 
  <xsl:template match="breed[text()='GSD' and parent::dog[name='Fido']]">
    <breed>Labrador</breed>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<dog>
    <name>Fido</name>
    <breed>Labrador</breed>
</dog>
```

Comment: Well I need it to be specific to another child value i.e. I would only want it to change breed for Fido, not for any other dogs with the GSD breed if that makes sense.

Comment: @AAlred - I'd change the match to `dog[name='Fido']/breed`.

Comment: @DanielHaley I'll try that.

Comment: @DanielHaley how would it handle doing that if say the name was a variable passed in through xsltproc?

Comment: @AAlred - In XSLT 1.0 you can't reference variables or parameters (if passed in through xsltproc it would have to be an `xsl:param`) in the match. You'd need to use an `xsl:choose` to test the value. I'll add a separate answer to show an example.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thank you. That would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

So from taking Daniel's answer and running with it, this is ultimately what gave me the best solution. (I am paraphrasing the code for obvious reasons but it should suffice). I am still saying that Daniel's answer will work because in most situations it will be fine but I ended up needing a way to handle additional options that I was unaware of when creating the question.

```
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
           <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="../dog[name = $dog.variable.name]:>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="optionalParams"/>
        .
        .
        .
        <breed>Labrador</breed>
    </xsl:template>
```